# How can I get sum candles (start at beginning of graph)?

Tags: tradingview-api

I want to get the total number of candles I have on my chart. I manage to do this in several ways, but none work with the "xxx" command :

```
var int total_candles = 0
if barstate.islast
    total_candles := bar_index + 1
```

and when I call my variable :

```
compteur = input.int(defval = total_candles , title='Nombre de bougies')
```

I get the following errors:

```
14:11:07    
Erreur à 37:31 Cannot call 'input.int' with argument 'defval'='total_candles'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'const int' is expected.
14:11:07    
Erreur à 187:18 The end value of the "for" loop must be a number.
```

I want to start my line at the very beginning of my graph, and this, regardless of its length.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pinescript you can't use variables in the input command :

> An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'const int' is
> expected.

The `const int` needed in the input command can't be a calculated value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

So is it possible to count the number of candles (sum) shown by my chart and get an INT format ? (and not a "series int" format) ?

Comment: No, it is a problem with pinescript : once a variable is calculated, it is a serie and we can't transform a serie (serie int)to a const type (int for example).